# How to create an alias to get a column?

Tags: bash, alias, cut-command

Hello I would like to perform an alias to get an specific colum, parameter using a separator in order to achieve this i decided to use the cut command I created the alias as follows, and I saved it in the corresponding bashrc file:

```
alias getColumn='cat $1 | cut -d'$2' -f'$3''
```

However when I tested it I got:

```
VirtualBox:~$ getColumn /tmp/tmp.9Eusfk5cKZ , 3
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.

SeVirtualBox:~$ getColumn /tmp/tmp.9Eusfk5cKZ "," "3"
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
cond try:
```

After feedback from here I tried:

```
#function to get a column
function getColumn() {
    cut -d"$2" -f"$3" "$1"
}
```

However I got:

```
VirtualBox:~$ getColumn topics " " 2
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
```

I am using ubuntu for this proves,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `bash` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.  If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used.

Try something like this in your `.bashrc` instead:

```
getColumn() {
    cut -d"$2" -f"$3" "$1"
}
```

Comment: @neo33 A function is *definitely* the better solution in this case. An alias cannot do what you want it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50899/discussion-between-wjandrea-and-neo33).